# Отладка C/C++ в VS Code в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, linux, c, отладка, visual-studio-code

Собственно, кто использует VS Code работает ли у вас режим отладки? В плане точек остановки, просмотра контрольных значений. Или я что то не так запускаю, ибо просто терминал запускается, но не могу попасть на любую точку останова. Просто фраза от MS немного дает задуматься.

> Debugging is currently tested and officially supported for Ubuntu 14.04 (x64). We are working on supporting other Linux distributions and OS X. You are welcome to try these although there may be issues.

Файл launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "This project",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "launchOptionType": "Local",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": []
        }
    ]
}
```